# formik does not work with initial value new Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, formik

I am trying to have initial value of date like this, but when component renders it gives me error like

```
const formik = useFormik ({
    initialValues: {
    dob: new Date ()
    }
})
```

while doing so I am getting following error

> Uncaught TypeError: date.isBefore is not a function

I am using formik with material UI Date Picker as below

```
 <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
           name="dob"
           id="dob"
           variant="standard"
           label="dob"
           value={formik.values.dob}
           renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} />
           )}
           onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue('dob', value, true)}
                error={formik?.touched?.dob && formik?.errors?.dob ? true : false}
                helperText={formik.touched.dob && formik.errors.dob}
      />
 </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DatePicker from MUI (Material UI), the date has to be in `dayjs.Dayjs` type.

In `initialValues`, instead of `dob: new Date ()`, do `dob: dayjs()`. That way you will have the current date and time in `dob`.

Later on, when you want to convert it to a javascript `Date` object, do `dob.toDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using MaterialUI v6 with dayjs

```
<DatePicker
    disableFuture
    label="Date of Birth"
    id="dateOfBirth"
    name="dateOfBirth"
    value={formik.values.dateOfBirth}
    onChange={(value) => {
      formik.setFieldValue("dateOfBirth", dayjs(value).format());
    }}
    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
    error={
      formik.touched.dateOfBirth &&
      Boolean(formik.errors.dateOfBirth)
    }
    helperText={
      formik.touched.dateOfBirth && formik.errors.dateOfBirth
    }
 />
```

Comment: Please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.